When did the Story of the Mekoshesh happen?
Rashi in Parshas Shelach, Bamidbar 15:32 says that the story of the Mekoshesh happened on the second Shabbat the Jews spent in the desert.

ויהיו … במדבר וימצאו. בִּגְנוּתָן שֶׁל יִשְׂרָאֵל דִּבֵּר הַכָּתוּב, שֶׁלֹא שָׁמְרוּ אֶלָּא שַׁבָּת רִאשׁוֹנָה, וּבַשְּׁנִיָּה בָא זֶה וְחִלְּלָהּ (ספרי):
ויהיו ... במדבר וימצאו AND [WHEN THE CHILDREN OF ISRAEL] WERE IN THE DESERT, THEY FOUND [A MAN THAT PICKED UP WOOD ON THE SABBATH DAY] — (This must mean when they first came into the wilderness, and) Scripture is speaking here to the disparagement of the Israelites viz., that they kept the first Sabbath only, for on the second this man came and desecrated it (Sifrei Bamidbar 113).

As such, this story occurred before מתן תורה
Later on, in 15:34 , Rashi writes that the Moshe knew that the death penalty is given for the transgression of Shabbat, but he didn't know which death penalty

כי לא פרש מה יעשה לו. בְּאֵיזוֹ מִיתָה יָמוּת, אֲבָל יוֹדְעִים הָיוּ שֶׁמְּחַלֵּל שַׁבָּת בְּמִיתָה (שם ע"ח):
כי לא פרש מה יעשה לו [AND, THEY PLACED HIM IN WARD] BECAUSE IT WAS NOT EXPLAINED WHAT SHOULD BE DONE WITH HIM — i.e. what kind of death penalty he was to receive had not yet been explained, but they were fully aware that one who desecrates the Sabbath is punishable by some death penalty (Sifrei Bamidbar 114; Sanhedrin 78b; cf. Rashi on Leviticus 24:12).

The gemara in Sanhedrin 78b states that Moshe knew that a death penalty needed to be given from (Ki Tisah 31:14)

מחלליה מות יומת

Given that parshas Ki Tisah is after Matan Torah, it was also already after the second Shabbat in the desert, so how could Rashi also say that the story of the Mekoshesh happened on the second Shabbat.
The Torah Temimah asks this question and proposes that the sources Rashi brings argue on each other as to the timing of the story of the Mekoshesh.
Are there any other answers to this question, especially since Rashi brings both without noting such a machlokes?

I understood the Rashi in 15:32 to mean the second shabbat after Mattan Torah. Meaning that although the Jews got the the commandment of Shabbat in Marah, punishment didn't begin until after the giving of the Torah, when that Shabbat was given as one of the 10 commandments.
You can see the Gur Aryeh on this Rashi, at the end, brings two reasons why we don't count the first Shabbat from Marah:

ואף על גב דבמרה אפקידו על שבת (שבת פז ע"ב), ומוכח מן המקרא דהיה קודם שבת זה ב' שבתות, כמו שכתבו התוספות בפרק רבי עקיבא (שם) , ואם כן היו יותר שומרים מן שבת אחת, דסבירא ליה כמאן דאמר בפרק רבי עקיבא (שם) אף על גב דאפקידו במרה על שבת – אתחומין לא אפקידו, ולכך לא נקרא 'שבת ראשונה', כיון דלא אפקידו אכל המצות. ואפילו למאן דאמר דאפקידו גם כן אתחומין, נראה, כיון דלא כתב בתורה שבת של מרה, רק "שם שם לו חוק ומשפט ושם נסהו" (שמות טו, כה), לא הוי זה בכלל תורה שנתן לישראל, כי לא היה זה רק כמו שאר המצות שנתן קודם שקבלו התורה, כמו שאר מצות בני נח. ובפרק ארבע מיתות (סנהדרין נו ע"ב) 'עשר מצות נצטוו ישראל במרה; שבע שקבלו עליהם בני נח, הוסיפו עליהן שבת ודינין וכבוד אב ואם', עד כאן. מדקאמר 'הוסיפו עליהן וכו", שמע מינה שענין המצות שנצטוו במרה משפטם כמו שבע מצות לבני נח, ולא נחשב זה מכלל שבת שכתב בתורה. והחילוק, שאין להם רק כללות ולא פרטות ודקדוקים, שלא נתנו להם רק הלכות שבת, ולא דקדוקיה ופרטותיה. ולפיכך לא נקרא 'שבת ראשון' רק כאשר כתב בתורה שבת, והוא שבת של פרשת המן (שמות טז, טו-כט), ואז ניתנו פרטותיה ודקדוקיה. ועיין לעיל בפרשת בשלח


The Maskil LeDavid, after asking your exact question (among others) and also pointing out that it couldn't be the second Shabbat After Mattan Torah either, since Moshe was on the mountain, says that it must mean the first and second shabbat after the Spies and decree to stay in the desert for 40 years.
